# file.seek() and file.write() issue when writing to a binary file

Tags: python, binary, byte, pickle

So, I have my code set up to read an array and write it to a binary file.

```
import sys
import pickle
offset = 0
UncompressedLookup = {}
f = open('/Users/shivangisingh/Desktop/InformationRetrieval/UCIndex.txt', 'wb')
for k, v in uncompressed_dic.items():
    UncompressedLookup[k] = {'offset': offset,
                             'size': sys.getsizeof(v),
                             '#ofdocumnetsInCollection': termstats[k]['#ofdocumnetsInCollection'] ,
                             '#ofoccurancesInCollection' : termstats[k]['#ofoccurancesInCollection'] }
    f.seek(offset)
    pickle.dump(v,f)
    offset= f.tell()

f.close()
```

When I print a few occurrences of the `UncompressedLookup`:

```
i=0
for k, v in UncompressedLookup.items():
    if (i==5):
        break
    print(k,v)
```

I get:

```
scene {'offset': 0, 'size': 19152, '#ofdocumnetsInCollection': 747, '#ofoccurancesInCollection': 779}
venice {'offset': 5071, 'size': 1096, '#ofdocumnetsInCollection': 25, '#ofoccurancesInCollection': 78}
```

That is weird because when I start at 0 and pickle 19152 bytes of data the next offset should be at 19152 but as we can see it is at 5071. I am confused.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` has nothing to do with the number of bytes when pickled. In fact `sys.getsizeof` is rarely useful for anything and often misleading.

Comment: Python is not C

Answer (score 2):

As @Alex Hall mentioned in a comment, `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't have anything to do with the size of the data being put into `pickle` file. To determine what you need/want to know, you can temporarily store pickled data in a string, which you can measure, and then write it to file manually yourself.

Your question doesn't have code that reproduce the problem. But here's some simple sample code that shows how to pickle the items in a dictionary and create an index that can be used later—in conjunction with `seek()`—to randomly read back any item that was in it. (Assuming that's your ultimate goal, of course.)

```
import random
import pickle

uncompressed_dic = {'a': 1, 'b': (2, 3, 4), 'c': 'text'}  # Sample data.

with open('UCIndex.txt', 'wb') as f:
    UncompressedLookup = {}
    offset = 0

    for key, value in uncompressed_dic.items():
        pkldata = pickle.dumps(value)
        size = len(pkldata)
        UncompressedLookup[key] = {'offset': offset, 'size': size}
        f.write(pkldata)
        offset += size


# Read items back in random order using UncompressedLookup dict.
keys = list(uncompressed_dic.keys())
random.shuffle(keys)

i = 0
while keys:
    if i >= 5:
        break
    key = keys.pop()
    offset = UncompressedLookup[key]['offset']
    size = UncompressedLookup[key]['size']
    with open('UCIndex.txt', 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(offset)
        pkldata = f.read(size)
        value = pickle.loads(pkldata)
    print((key, value))
```

Sample output:

```
('b', (2, 3, 4))
('c', 'text')
('a', 1)
```

Comment: I *believe* you should be able to just `pickle.load(f)` once you've used `seek`